# The future of functional programming

Tags: functional-programming

I have recently attended a lecture about functional programming by the CEO of a very successful company. The company relies very heavily (almost exclusively) on functional programming. The actual language they use is F#.

This man claims that functional programming is poised to take over as the next big thing. I have heard similar claims about this in the past but it never seemed to happen.

Because functional programming is very different from imperative programming, and would take a considerable amount of time to become fluent in, is it worth it? Do you think that there is a big future for functional programming?

Comment: You might want to try this question at [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth getting to know a functional language but not because it will get big in the future or land you a good job, but rather because you'll become a better programmer by knowing something besides OOP and procedural languages.

Answer (score 1):

There are almost as many different opinions on this as there are readers of stackoverflow. Everybody has their own crystal ball :-)

Answer (score 1):

Elements of functional programming will be (are) included in mainstream languages. The next COD won't be written in Haskell though.

Answer (score 1):

I certainly think that functional programming will always have a place. I don't know if it will be the next big thing, considering that it's been around for 50 years. I do think that it's worth it to learn a functional language. As ESR has said:

"Lisp is worth learning for the profound enlightenment experience you will have when you finally get it; that experience will make you a better programmer for the rest of your days, even if you never actually use Lisp itself a lot."

Source: [How To Become A Hacker by Eric S. Raymond](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html)

Comment: but now that multi-core processors are taking over....